# unzip two different kind of file extensions

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, zip

Note here, .zip and .jar is just an example, my file extensions are different. Suppose I have a directory which can contain number of zip files

```
a.zip b.zip c.zip
```

AND/OR

```
z.jar x.jar y.jar
```

along with other contents.

I want to unzip them all.

I tried

```
unzip -q *.zip
```

and

```
unzip -q *.jar
```

But when the folder does not contain .jar files, the second command would fail

```
unzip:  cannot find or open *.jar, *.jar.zip or *.jar.ZIP.

No zipfiles found.
```

This is problematic for me as it an error my script would exit. I want to silently unzip the *.zip and *.jar without errors. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `nullglob` in bash:

```sh
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ tee foo.zip bar.zip </dev/null
$ echo *.zip *.jar
bar.zip foo.zip
```

The `nullglob` option changes the behaviour of a non-matching glob from becoming a literal string to being removed entirely.

However, this will likely not suffice in your particular use case, as `unzip` won't know what to do if it is passed no arguments. You should check if there are zips/jars to unzip first, like so:

```sh
shopt -s nullglob
zips=( *.zip )
jars=( *.jar )
(( "${#zips[@]}" )) && unzip -q "${zips[@]}"
(( "${#jars[@]}" )) && unzip -q "${jars[@]}"
```

Or all at once (if applicable):

```sh
shopt -s nullglob
zipsandjars=( *.zip *.jar )
(( "${#zipsandjars[@]}" )) && unzip -q "${zipsandjars[@]}"
```

In POSIX shell something similar can also be done like so:

```sh
for file in *.zip *.jar; do
    if [ "$file" != "*.zip" ] && [ "$file" != "*.jar" ]; then
        unzip -q "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This one still gave, jars were not found. when my directory did not have .jars

Comment: Okay, I had not set the `shopt -s nullglob` I guess that is the key.

Comment: great solution. Why does ${#zipsandjars[@]} have to be surrounded with quotes?

Comment: @ChandraRavoori It doesn't, it's just good practise to always quote your expansions.

Comment: yes, where the possibility of embedded whitespace exists. in this specific case would not ${#zipsandjars[@]}  always resolve to a number?

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ChrisDown. I was use this within a ruby program, I thought, I could a check for types using program and then unzip accordingly. This information is still immensely useful.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran If you truly want to check types, look at the file magic. That should be fairly straightforward to do in ruby.